# Tips for integration with indicator functions

Tags: probability, integration

[background] I'm working on a probability-proportional-to-size sample design and trying to calculate my inclusion probabilities. Given the specifics of the problem, this results in me needing to integrate a joint probability with an indicator function. I can integrate this numerically using `scipy`, but would love to use an analytical formula if I can derive one.

[question] I'm looking for tips for how to analytically solve this problem under different probability assumptions. I think there might be solutions if I incorporate the indicator function into the bounds, or if I convert to polar coordinates, I just haven't been able to figure out how.

Let:
$P((x_{j}, y_{j})) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty Q((x_m, y_m)) \times \mathbb{I}\{(x_{j} - x_m)^2 + (y_{j} - y_m)^2 \leq R^2\} dx_mdy_m$

Where $Q((x_m, y_m))$, could be either of the below (uniform or normal in 2D):

- $Q((x_m, y_m)) = \frac{1}{\pi T^2}\mathbb{I}\{x_m^2 + y_m^2 \leq T^2\}$ for $T$ defined/fixed
- $Q((x_m, y_m)) = N\left((x_m, y_m) \mid \mu_i, \sigma^2_i\right)$ for $(\mu_i, \sigma^2_i)$ defiend/fixed

Answer (score 1):

> I think there might be solutions if I incorporate the indicator function into the bounds, or if I convert to polar coordinates, I just haven't been able to figure out how.

Well, $\{(x_m,y_m)\mid (x_j−x_m)^2+(y_j−y_m)^2\leqslant R^2\}$ is a disc of radius $R$ centred on the point $(x_j,y_j)$, so the polar coordinate transformation would be:

$$\begin{align}P(x_j,y_j) &= \iint_{(x_j−x_m)^2+(y_j−y_m)^2\leqslant R^2}Q(x_m, y_m)\,\mathrm d(x_m, y_m) \\[1ex] &= \int_0^R\!\!\!\!\int_0^{2\pi} r\,Q(x_j+r\cos\theta,y_j+r\sin\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d r\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks Graham! I like the direction this is headed. Do you mind including a couple more steps in your derivation? This was the step I was having trouble deriving on my own